# Lodash js check if value is different to null

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a question, is there a method in lodash for validate a key value ?

I have the nex object:

```
var obj = [
              { name:'A', active:false, quantity : null },
              { name:'B', active:false, quantity : null },
              { name:'C', active:true,  quantity : 4    },
              { name:'D', active:false, quantity : null },
              { name:'E', active:false, quantity : null }
          ];
```

What i want is, validate if quantity is different to null using a lodash method witout a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `_.filter` to determine this. Try

```
_.filter(obj, function(o){
        return o.quantity !== null
  })
```

or another method

```
_.filter(obj, function(o){
     return !o.quantity
})
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I used _.isEmpty method for return true or false if the object have not null values !_.isEmpty( _.filter(obj, function(o){return o.quantity !== null}))

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve this by using javascript itself

```js
var obj = [
              { name:'A', active:false, quantity : null },
              { name:'B', active:false, quantity : null },
              { name:'C', active:true,  quantity : 4    },
              { name:'D', active:false, quantity : null },
              { name:'E', active:false, quantity : null }
          ];
          
 var predicate=(item)=> item.quantity!=null;         
 var new_obj= obj.filter(predicate);
 console.log(new_obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `_.reject` with shorthand:

```
_.reject(obj, { quantity: null })
```

or using `_.isEmpty`:

```
_.reject(obj, o => _.isEmpty(o.quantity))
```